# Lightning Components: are standard list views overridable by Flexipages or Lightning Components yet or on the roadmap?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, list-view

The current list-views in LEX are in some respects less powerful than their predecessors in Aloha:

- no more checkboxes and multi-edit
- no more inline-edit for the Name-field
- massive padding is causing less information displayed plus increased need of scrolling in y and x direction

[image]

At this point the only way to override the list views I found is by Visualforce. I just want to confirm, that I didn't miss anything. It this actually the only way:

[image]

Or is there any other option for an override by a Flexipage or Lightning Component yet existing or on the roadmap? Overriding by a Visualforce-page feels not the right way to do this in LEX...

Any hint would help me to plan ahead.

Answer (score 3):

As per the latest release notes of [winter 17](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_sales_productivity_list_views_parent.htm) there is a feature for multiselect but to take mass  action you still need a visualforce button

[image]

Also some fields on opportunity and other objects are editable inline

[image]

The spring [pre-release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_sales_productivity_list_views_inline_edit.htm) makes this feature GA

All the info provided is from the release notes and will have to wait from sfdc to comment on roadmap for specific lightning interface for the list views

Comment: On Account Listviews how were you able to get the checkboxes?   I don't get those as you see in the screenshot above and the release notes don't tell me how to activate them.